# Correct syntax to put multiple options into single case to reduce case_when cases dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to put multiple possibilities into a case_when case rather than repeating?

For example in this data I want `check` to be `T` if `x1` contains "foo" or "bar".

```
 q= tibble(x1 = c("foo", "bar", "foo", "bu", "ba"))
```

I have tried:

```
q%>%mutate(check = case_when(x1== "foo"|"bar" ~T,
                             T~F))

q%>%mutate(check = case_when(x1== "foo|bar" ~T,
                             T~F))
```

These come up with an error or all `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `%in%` instead of `==`.

Is the string in x1 found in the vector c("foo", "bar")

```
q%>%mutate(check = case_when(x1 %in% c("foo", "bar")~T,
                             T~F))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  x1    check
  <chr> <lgl>
1 foo   TRUE 
2 bar   TRUE 
3 foo   TRUE 
4 bu    FALSE
5 ba    FALSE
```